# Toolbar is not displaying in category list and search result page Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, database, toolbar

Toolbar is not displaying in list page. There is no any changes in layout file catalog_category_view.xml and phtml file toolbar.phtml, these files are unchange. And there is no any module that removing toolbar for list page. Here is one scenario, when toolbar is working. When i change my magento link db with older one then toolbar is displaying.
But i need to link magento with new db (in which toolbar is not working).
How can i find the exact issue in which case toolbar is hidding.